# Silverlight: DataGrid inside ListBox. Binding on DataGrid Column to a parent listbox's ItemsSource property. Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, collections, datagrid, listbox, itemssource

I'm a little puzzled with this one. I have a Collection called "AllProducts", which has a collection inside called "ProductGroups" (to group items separately) which inside contain a collection of "Product" objects called "LineItems" (the actual items).

To set this up, I have set a ListBox with a DataGrid inside the itemtemplate for the ListBox's Items. Setting the ItemsSource of the listbox to "ProductGroups" and the DataGrid(In the itemtemplate) has an ItemsSource pointing to LineItems.

The DataGrid contains Columns:
"Select" -- A checkbox and a radiobutton
"Image" -- string
"Name" -- string
"Description" -- string
"Price" -- string

The "ProductGroup" collection has a bool property called "IsListItem" per group, which is supposed to tell me if you can select multiple or a single item for that group (hence the checkbox and radiobutton in the first column of the DataGrid). I want the checkbuttons and radiobuttons visibility property to be bound to "IsListItem" bool which I have already set up with a BoolToVisibility converter with an "IsInverted" property to switch them back and forth.

The problem that I'm running into is that I want the first column of the DataGrid which contains the checkboxes/radiobuttons to be bound to the IsLineItem of ProductGroups (which is the ListBox's ItemsSource. But Since the DataGrid's ItemsSource is bound to LineItems, the DataContext of the DataGrid is set to LineItems and I can't access anything outside of it.

Here's some code to help:

ListBox XAML:

```
<sdk:TabItem Header="Pmt" x:Name="Payment">
                <Canvas x:Name="PaymentRoot" DataContext="{Binding Products.ProductGroups}">
                    <Rectangle Height="418" Canvas.Top="-14" Width="560" Style="{StaticResource MappingRectangleBG}" />
                    <StackPanel Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20" Width="520" Height="360">
                        <ListBox x:Name="lstProductGroups"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProductListItem}" />      
                    </StackPanel>
                </Canvas>
            </sdk:TabItem>
```

ListBox ItemTemplate XAML:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgLineItems" ItemsSource="{Binding LineItems}">               
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Select">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding IsListType, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                                <RadioButton Visibility="{Binding IsListType, Converter={StaticResource inverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" GroupName="{Binding GroupName}"/>
                            </StackPanel>                               
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Image">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Height="50" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Name"
            Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Price"
            Binding="{Binding Price}" />
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>

    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And my Objects:

```
public class AllProducts
{

    public IEnumerable<ProductOptionGroup> ProductGroups;
}


public class ProductOptionGroup
{

    public string GroupName;

    public IEnumerable<Product> LineItems;

    public bool IsListType;
}


public class Product
{

    public int ID;

    public int OrdinalNumber;

    public string Name;

    public string Description;

    public Decimal Price;

    public string ImageUrl;

    public CartItemType Type;
}
```

(MichaelS): I tried setting it to the Parent "PaymentRoot" Canvas' DataContext but it isn't doing anything for me. Here is what I tried:

```
<CheckBox Visibility="{Binding ElementName=PaymentRoot, Path=DataContext.IsListType, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
<RadioButton Visibility="{Binding ElementName=PaymentRoot, Path=DataContext.IsListType, Converter={StaticResource inverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" GroupName="{Binding ElementName=PaymentRoot, Path=DataContext.GroupName}"/>
```

(MichaelS): here's how it's set up in my VM:
private AllProducts products;

```
public AllProducts Products
    {
        get
        {
            return products;
        }
        set
        {
            //Products.ProductGroups[0].LineItems[0].
            products = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Products");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the following question can help you: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385784/access-parent-datacontext-in-listbox-in-silverlight)

Comment: I tried setting it to the Parent "PaymentRoot" Canvas' DataContext but it isn't doing anything different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it fixed! What I had to end up doing was getting rid of the DataGrid altogether because a lot of controls from the toolkit seem to have that bug not being able to bind outside even through Element Binding.

I turned the DataGrid into a ListBox with another DataTemplate for the LineItems completely customizing the look of it to achieve a similar look that I had with the DataGrid.

Also to note: I tried at first binding to the StackPanel outside of the DataTemplate through Element Binding but it seemed to have a problem with that. So I set the grid inside the DataTemplate's DataContext and then I made the checkbox and radiobutton bound to the grid inside the Parent Listbox's dataTemplate through element binding and that did the trick!

Here is some working code for anybody who runs into this same issue later on!:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LineItemsTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100">
            <StackPanel Height="40" Orientation="Vertical">
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding Name}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=GridDataHolder, Path=DataContext.IsListType, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" GroupName="{Binding ElementName=GridDataHolder, Path=DataContext.GroupName}"/>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=GridDataHolder, Path=DataContext.IsListType, Converter={StaticResource inverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Height="50" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ProductListItem">
    <StackPanel x:Name="GridDataHolder">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding GroupName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="lstProductGroups"  ItemsSource="{Binding LineItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LineItemsTemplate}">
            </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<sdk:TabItem Header="Pmt" x:Name="Payment">
            <Canvas>
                <Rectangle Height="418" Canvas.Top="-14" Width="560" Style="{StaticResource MappingRectangleBG}" />
                <ScrollViewer Height="389" Width="545" x:Name="PaymentRoot" DataContext="{Binding Products.ProductGroups}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <ListBox x:Name="lstProductGroups"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProductListItem}" />      
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Canvas>
        </sdk:TabItem>
```

**Thanks MichaelS for all your help! You got me going the right way!**

Comment: You are welcome Alex!
So you finally did changed your dataTemplate. To be honest the new dataTemplate looks much cleaner and readable..

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
The below code won't work since it's a known issue that was discovered late in the Silverlight 3 timeframe.
Setting the Binding in the LoadingRow event using column.GetCellContent(e.Row) should solve the issue.

In this particular case , you want be able to do that since the dataGrid itself is a dataTemplate of another control.

---

Try this:
Wrap your `datagrid` with another `Grid`. Name it, and use it for the element binding.
This code should work:

```
<StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="GridDataHolder">
            <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgLineItems" ItemsSource="{Binding LineItems}">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Select">
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding ElementName=GridDataHolder, Path=DataContext.IsListType, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                                    <RadioButton Visibility="{Binding ElementName=GridDataHolder, Path=DataContext.IsListType, Converter={StaticResource inverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" GroupName="{Binding ElementName=GridDataHolder, Path=DataContext.GroupName}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Image">
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Height="50" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Name"
        Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Price"
        Binding="{Binding Price}" />
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

By the way, i'm not sure if binding works with public members, you may need to change those binded members to public properties.

Comment: Thanks MichaelS, unfortunately I tried using the Grid for element binding but to no avail. I showed the public member to show the structure of the objects, but in reality I got it from a web service and set it to a property in my VM.

Comment: @Alex, If the _listbox_ is binded to _ProductGroups_, then the _Datacontex_ of each _listbox.item_ will be _ProductOptionGroup_.
Hence, The wrapping Grid Datacontext will be also _ProductOptionGroup_, and you should be able to use it for element binding.
I made a small sample using your objects, and a listbox inside a listbox, (just because _listbox_ is less code). Hope it will be useful for you. Please update on how it went.
Download from here: [ParentElementBindingSample](https://skydrive.live.com/#!/?cid=c98bb2b1515f256f&sc=documents&uc=1&id=C98BB2B1515F256F%212203)

Comment: Weird, I have the same code structure as you. It's just not working. I have breakpoints in my VM and IvalueConverter and it never hits the IValueConverter at all.

Comment: What has me even more puzzled is that if I grab the checkbox and radiobutton and put them right above the DataGrid it works great and hits the IVC like it should. It is just failing to bind INSIDE the datagrid

Comment: Yeah I feel I'm really close, just not finding that "AHA!" moment quite yet! Will report back when I find out the issue! :)

Comment: I tried with a datagrid as you said, it really doesn't work. Interesting. I'll have a dipper look on it later. Wondering whats the difference between the listbox binding and the datagrid. Maybe because of the extra level of cell.datatemplate. Any way, please update, this is interesting stuff.

Comment: @Alex, See the following [link](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/111060/351300.aspx). It appears to be a known bug from silverlight 3. Try set the Binding in the LoadingRow event using column.GetCellContent(e.Row)

Comment: Not exactly sure how to call the LoadingRow event if my DataGrid is inside the ListBox's Item DataTemplate in the styles.xaml

Comment: Sorry, i was a little misleading with my last comment. If your Datagrid wasn't a DataTemplate by itself, you could have used the LoadingRow Event.
With your case i think you should consider to change your datacontext object structure, or datatemplate.

Comment: I read on the post you posted on silverlight.net: "I specifically figured out that Element binding to elemets outside the data template wouldnt work in the datatemplates for the various controls provided with the Silverlight toolkit.(The same however works if i am using generic controls like llistbox etc.)"

but it's not working with a ListBox inside. I think I might have to implement the DataContext Proxy  here: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx